# Can you replace upper kitchen cabinets without removing tile/glass backsplash?

Tags: cabinets, removal, replacement, backsplash, custom-cabinetry

Can upper kitchen cabinets be removed and replaced with new ones without damaging a tile or glass backsplash? If not, when the backsplash is removed, can it be done without damaging the granite countertop? [image: backsplash and cabinets]

Comment: Even though those tiles probably aren't cheap, they're probably cheaper than the labor required to preserve them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it *should* be possible to remove the cabinets without damaging the tile.  However, the replacement cabinets will have to be the exact same size, or you'll have some tile work to do (adding or removing tile).

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the tile was set around the cabinetry, which is typical. When the cabinets are removed the grout joint between the cabinets and tile will be damaged. Therefore, at a minimum, that joint will need to be reworked.

That said, it would be a daunting challenge to have cabinets made to such close specifications that they fit well against the existing tile. Variation in wall plumb and plane, among other factors, would make that an impractical goal, depending on the complexity of the existing cabinetry.

One approach would be to remove the mosaic tile down to an appropriate uniform level throughout, remove the cabinets, repair and paint the drywall above the remaining tile, install the new cabinetry, and then apply a finishing row of bullnose accent tile above the backsplash.